# when user is on window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a small game in js/jquery and I am looking for an event allowing to pause the function and timer when the player is not on the window or leave the window, do you know this event, I could not find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event) and [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event) events.

```js
addEventListener('blur', function(){
  console.log('Window no longer active');
});

addEventListener('focus', function(){
  console.log('Window is now active');
});
```